# How to change GlobalPlatform Key which is imported to javacard by put_sc_key command in GPShell

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I imported a Secure Messaging key on javacard and i can open secure channel by new key successfully by gpshell. But I want to change new key not adding new one. How can i do it? i have to import new key and delete old one or anything else i have to do?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As per  [Global platform card specification](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwi6yYXb0qnMAhVV1I4KHe0iCRoQFggnMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.win.tue.nl%2Fpinpasjc%2Fdocs%2FCard%2520Spec%2520v2.1.1%2520v0303.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHxA_05sX_EWg1k61lDws8Hqz6blw&sig2=AF1iL_JwhIHN9qVUXwGcbg&bvm=bv.119745492,d.c2E&cad=rja) it says:-

[image]

Here you just need to fire PUT KEY command with same or a different key version number ( Parameter P1) but the same Key Identifier ( Parameter P2) as the key being replaced/changed with new one.